# org-mode - How to export basic list as outline, not TOC

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have the Latex commands in my org mode file:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{fontspec}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setmonofont[Scale=0.9]{Latin Modern Mono}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setromanfont{Accanthis ADF Std No3}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \linespread{1.5}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}

#+LATEX_HEADER \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment itemize*
#+ATTR_LATEX: :options [label={}, itemjoin={,}, itemjoin*={, and}]
```

followed by a simple org list that doesn't go deeper than four levels.  When I export as latex and open as a PDF, it keeps giving me a table of contents and then my list.  I just want to write an outline.  Anyone know how to do this?  My google searches aren't turning up anything useful and the above is from the org-mode manual.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `toc` option:

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
```

See the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Table-of-Contents.html) for details.

Comment: Thaks - I tried that orignially and didn't get what I expected - so I mut have done something worng / different.  Works now.  Much appreciated!